# When does the Cisco IOS SNMP "ifCounterDiscontinuityTime" counter change?

Tags: cisco, snmp

According to Cisco SNMP object navigator, `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime`(1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19) counter is the value of `sysUpTime` on the most recent occasion at which any one or more of this interfaces counters suffered a discontinuity. How to cause this discontinuity? I have tried to disable router interface("shutdown" and "no shutdown" for five seconds), removing physical cable for five seconds from router port, but still the value of `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime` is zero:

```
# snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19.1 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19.2 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19.3 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19.4 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19.5 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
#
```

I even caused `Counter32` type counter to wrap, but the `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime` stayed zero:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.1.1 ifInOctets.10107
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.10107 = Counter32: 4278115545
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19.10107
IF-MIB::ifCounterDiscontinuityTime.10107 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.1.1 ifInOctets.10107
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.10107 = Counter32: 18656065
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19.10107
IF-MIB::ifCounterDiscontinuityTime.10107 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
$
```

`192.168.1.1` is a Cisco switch and `10107` is a SNMP `ifIndex` for port Gi0/7.

When does the SNMP `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime` counter change in Cisco IOS?

Comment: Hmm..i think its more of a router or connection problem??idk..i'm gonna look into this but, for sure its a timed-out sure it maybe the signal didn't get a good respond.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ifCounterDiscontinuityTime is triggered when interfaces are dynamically removed from a device and then that same interface is dynamically re-added. I tested this using a loopback interface but I believe the behavior would be the same for modular interface whose existence would change based on whether or not the module was present. The steps to reproduce this are below and there is some further reading on this topic in the RFC here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2863#section-3.1.5

**1. Create loopback 100 and find it's ifindex**

```
router1#conf t
router1(config)#int loopback100
router1(config-if)#end
```

---

```
[user@host logs]$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY router1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2 | grep Loopback
IF-MIB::ifDescr.67 = STRING: Loopback100
```

**2. Check the current value of ifCounterDiscontinuityTime for Loopback100**

```
[user@host logs]$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY router1 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19.67
IF-MIB::ifCounterDiscontinuityTime.67 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
```

**3. Remove Loopback100 and check the value of ifCounterDiscontinuityTime**

```
router1(config)#no int loopback 100
```

---

```
[user@host logs]$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY router1 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19.67
IF-MIB::ifCounterDiscontinuityTime.67 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

**4. Re-add Loopback100 and check the value of ifCounterDiscontinuityTime**

```
router1(config)#int loopback 100

[user@host logs]$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY router1 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19.67
IF-MIB::ifCounterDiscontinuityTime.67 = Timeticks: (111308186) 12 days, 21:11:21.86
```

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that for example removal and insertion of `WS-X4306-GB` or `WS-X4448-GB-RJ45` line-cards in `WS-C4506` chassis will also cause `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime` to change. So basically `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime` will log the timestamp when interface became available for SNMP engine? If the interface has been available from the start, then the `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime` will stay 0?

Comment: If I am understanding the RFC correctly ifCounterDiscontinuityTime records the timestamp when the interface became present again using the same ifIndex. The purpose of this is that your SNMP monitoring software knows not to use stale interface counter data when comparing it to new interface counter data. The only time the ifCounterDiscontinuityTime value is initialized is when an interface is removed, then re-added with the same ifIndex it previously had, otherwise it would remain zero. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think discontinuity refers to an abnormality. I found [this](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.19#oidContent)

> The value of sysUpTime on the most recent occasion at which any one or
>   more of this interface's counters suffered a discontinuity. The
>   relevant counters are the specific instances associated with this
>   interface of any Counter32 or Counter64 object contained in the
>   ifTable or ifXTable. If no such discontinuities have occurred since
>   the last re- initialization of the local management subsystem, then
>   this object contains a zero value.

to me, that implies that "discontinuity" is related to bit-size-integer-rollover.

So if you see the sysTime change, you know that counters that are now showing smaller-than-last-time-checked values have, in fact, wrapped around, as if you had rebooted.

Comment: Thanks for reply! To be honest, this is bit confusing.. If I see `sysUpTime` change to smaller value than the last check then I would think that counters showing smaller-than-last-time-checked values are not wrapped around because device reloaded. Or did I misunderstood you somehow? In addition, I wrapped one `Counter32` type counter and it did not affect `ifCounterDiscontinuityTime`. I updated my initial post.